# Switch from one tab to other programatically

Tags: c#, winforms

In a `Windows Form`, while using tabControl1 how to switch from one tab to other(i.e tabPage1 to tabPage2) on button click in tabPage1..Tried a lot with

```
tabPage2.Show(); 
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = tabPage2;
```

etc but not giving any o/p...Please help

Comment: always see what LHS and RHS equates to. On one side you have an int field and on another you have TabPage control, hence the error. That said you have the right answer below. Do not forget to accept it by clicking the green tick on top left of the answer.

Comment: `tabControl.SelectedIndex = Ordinal` I find this to be the best approach..

Comment: Could you include a broader code sample?

Answer (score 6):

You should try using the [TabControl.SelectedTab Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx):

> Gets or sets the currently selected tab page.

The topic above also has the following remark:

> The tab page must be in the TabPages collection to make it the current
>   tab page.

In your case, this should work:

```
//somewhere in your code, you have to add first the TabPage to the TabControl
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage2);

tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
```

**[UPDATE]**

If that doesn't work either, it's likely you haven't associated the `button1_Click` method as the `button1`'s `Click` event handler. And it's even more likely that you just created the `button1` control in another control container of your form or the form itself and then **cutted and pasted** it to the `tabPage1` control.

That will remove the event handler.

Just reassign the `button1_Click` method as `button1`'s `Click` event handler and make sure you use the `SelectedTab` property (or `SelectedIndex` as  shown in some other answers and comments of this question).

Here's a reference to a similar problem: [cut and paste controls lost event handlers](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl/csharpide/thread/8a5d8c22-1eae-49a9-b972-79b2e851f46c).

Comment: @Adi0745 What exactly is not working, what is the error you get?

Comment: on the button click...I remain on the same tab i.e tabPage1

Comment: Have you added the `tabPage2` control to the `TabPages` collection of your `tabControl1`?

Comment: private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabPage2);

            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPage2;
            
            tabPage2.Focus();
        }

Comment: @Adi0745 you should put all your relevant code in the question.

Comment: @Alex Filipovici Thank you so much for paying attention..you all are doing great job here.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
tabControl1.SelectedPage = tabpage1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice the [TabControl.SelectedIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedindex.aspx) property is in integer. (You could also use the SelectedTab property as the other answers suggest)

So you set it to the tab you want selected :

```
tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

---

Here is a full blown sample based on the msdn code, (note it's not tested since I'm not on windows and don't have .NET setup here):

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    private TabControl tabControl1;
    private TabPage tabPage1;
    private TabPage tabPage2;
    private Button btn;

    private void MyTabs()
    {
        this.tabControl1 = new TabControl();
        this.tabPage1 = new TabPage();
        this.tabPage2 = new TabPage();
        this.btn = new Button();

        this.tabControl1.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
            this.tabPage1,
            this.tabPage2});
        this.tabControl1.Padding = new Point(15, 10);
        this.tabControl1.Location = new Point(35, 25);
        this.tabControl1.Size = new Size(220, 220);
        this.btn.Location = new Point(10, 250);

        // Selects THE FIRST tab initially.. 
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;

        this.tabPage1.Text = "myTabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;

        this.tabPage2.Text = "myTabPage2";
        this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;

        this.btn.Text = "Select myTabPage2";
        this.btn.Click += new EventHandler(btn_click);

        this.Size = new Size(400, 400);
        this.Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {
            this.tabControl1});
        this.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
    public void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 1;
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        MyTabs();
    }

    static void Main() 
    {
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to set `Focus` onto that tab.

Comment: @Bob. why would focus matter?

Comment: Its more a convenience thing if you have events that need to be handled when that page is shown.

Answer (score 0):

`this.tabControl1.SelectedTab = this.tabControl1.TabPages[1];`.